# Preselected values for angular-schema-form

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

Does angular-schema-form have a method to show preselected values?
When the titleMap on the select will set an integer, preselected values will show. But if it will set an object, I found no way of showing the correct name.

Is there anything to tie the object to, like with ng-options where you can set an attribute to compare them with the "track by" clause?

```
ng-options="option as option.name for option in array track by option.id"
```

In my example code, cats1 will set an object, cats2 will set an integer.

HTML:

```html
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="login-container">
        <form name="myForm" 
              sf-schema="schema" 
              sf-form="form" 
              sf-model="model">
          
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Controller:

```html
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.form = [
    {
      key: 'cats1',
      type: 'select',
      titleMap: [
        {value: {id: 0, name: "Leopard"}, name: "Leopard"},
        {value: {id: 1, name: "Tiger"}, name: "Tiger"}
      ]
    },
    {
      key: 'cats2',
      type: 'select',
      titleMap: [
        {value: 0, name: "Leopard"},
        {value: 1, name: "Tiger"}
      ]
    }
  ];

  $scope.schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "cats1": {
        "title": "Cats",
        "type": "object"
      },
      "cats2": {
        "title": "Cats",
        "type": "number"
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.model = {cats1: {id: 1, name: "Tiger"}, cats2: 1};
}]);
```

Here is a plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/0hK5Hrc9GXklfRwa6fjE?p=preview